# Adding textbox & button programmatically -> Button Click event with no content for textbox

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, event-handling

I'm pretty new to this and so far I haven't found any solution online which solves my problem.

I'd like to use controls by adding them programmatically, which works and the contents shows in the window, but as soon I want to save the content via button, the event handler doesn't get the variables passed to it.

I've got the following situation where I don't know what I miss. (WPF4, EF, VS2010)

In XAML I have a grid where I'd like to add eg. a textbox and a button from code behind like

```
<Grid  Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="2"  Name="textBox1" />
</Grid >
```

In code-behind:

```
private void CheckMatching ()
{
    TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();
    textBox2.Text = "textbox to fill";
    textBox2.Name = "textBox2";

    Grid1.Children.Add(textBox2);

    Button SaveButton = new Button();
    SaveButton.Name = "Save";
    SaveButton.Content = "Save";

    SaveButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(SaveButton_Click);
    Grid1.Children.Add(SaveButton);
}

private void SaveButton_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    // works fine 
    string ShowContent1 = textBox1.Text;

    // It doesn't show up in intellisense, so I cant use it yet
    string ShowContent2 = textBox2.Text;
}
```

I can access the content of the textbox in XAML or everything else set in XAML, but I don't get the content of anything else I set in code-behind. The content itself is shown in the window.

I tried different approaches already. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not a WPF issue but something very basic to the **Object Oriented Computer Programming**.

How can you **expect** that an object (`textBox2`) that was delcared and created locally  in `CheckMatching` method be available in another method like `SaveButton_Click`?

For that you can scope it class level.

```
 private TextBox textBox2;

 private void CheckMatching ()
 {
     this.textBox2 = new TextBox();
     this.textBox2.Text = "textbox to fill";
     this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";

     Grid1.Children.Add(this.textBox2);
     .....
 }

 private void SaveButton_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
 {
       string ShowContent1 = textBox1.Text; // works fine
       string ShowContent2 = this.textBox2.Text; // should work too
 }
```

And then you can also do it WPF way....

```
 private void SaveButton_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
 {
       string ShowContent1 = textBox1.Text; // works fine
       string ShowContent2 = ((TextBox)Grid1.Children[1]).Text; // should work too
 }
```